# How to run the command in async using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How to execute the command asynchronously using the robot framework. 
The below sample code is done using ansible, need to achieve using robot framework

```
- name: Capturing the Data flow
    shell: tcpdump -v -U -i eth1 host 8.8.8.8 -w /tmp/temhost.pcap
    become: yes
    async: 60
    poll: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) Library we can achieve , below is sample piece of code:

```
Library                Process
Suite Setup            Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown         Close Connection

    *** Test Cases ***
    Capturing The Traffic Flow
        ${tcpdump}=    Write  nohup sudo tcpdump -v -U host ${public_ip_gateway} -w ${TCPDUMPFILE} &
        Log            ${tcpdump}       console=${True}
        ${ping_out}=   Execute Command  ping -c 15 8.8.8.8      return_stdout=True
        Log            ${ping_out}          console=${True}
```